# I want a support company to do remote administration using SSH on our AWS EC2 instance (RHEL) using 2 factor authentication. How do i achieve this?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, remote-access, rhel

The supplier is based at different site and needs to connect over the internet. So the connection needs to be secure.

We have a Web app firewall (WAF) i know we need to open port 22.

I have looked at AWS workspace however this is for windows.

What is the best way to connect to a Red hat linux box.

The endpoint used by the supplier is their own and not issued by my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Google's PAM**, you should be able to invoke 2-factor authentication for ssh.

Following blog gives a nice step by step explanation on how to install and configure Google's PAM on linux machine.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-centos-7
- https://fatmin.com/2016/06/28/rhel-7-two-factor-ssh-via-google-authenicator/